# How to delete corrupted windows drivers from another os?

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-10

I had windows 8.1 and it said that windows 10 update is ready. I updated. Everything went fine. But there was a bug — right click (start menu is opened) took 20 seconds. I decided problem was video driver and downloaded nvidia windows 10 drivers.

I got black screen with cursor, didn't manage to get to login screen.

I tried "press ctrl, enter password and enter", but it didn't work.

But I have another windows on my hdd. How do I delete this drivers to reset default from another os? I mean, Can I boot up to another windows and delete drivers from hard disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before going the complicated way using another OS and such - does the OS under which you loaded the nVidia drivers boot up in Safe Mode..?

If it does, try this:

1. Delete the graphics card from Device Manager - **do not** reboot if asked.
2. Open a command prompt with administrator permissions and type del c:\windows\inf\oem*.*

What the scond point does is to remove installation information for drivers which are not native to Windows 10 and thus upon reboot, the OS will load either the default vga driver or the native nVidia driver for your graphics card.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, in safe mode happens same thing. No task manager, no desktop, no login screen. I loaded to Ubuntu and deleted oem files you mentioned. Didn't work :( I suppose I'm gonna have to go back to 8.1 till 10 gets stable.